# Dynamic Switching Of Column based on Size

Tags: java

We are not sure what would be the size of file on upload an image

For now, planning to go with medium blob and using mysql as database.

Assume, if the customer uploads more than 16MB, the DB column should be automatically changed to longblob to accomodate the file. This is to cover the edge scenario, however we may not sure whether it would happen

What is the best way to support or achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: What does it have to do with Java?

Comment: @Amongalen The project is done in java..that's the reason posted with Java tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is to define your database fields properly. You don't switch fields just because the file is larger than the datatype, that's bad design. Also, there are really no disadvantages from using a `LONGBLOB` from the start. If you want to limit the amount of data pasted into your database, you should already limit this in the java side, not rely on the database to do so.

Comment: Will there be a performance impact when defining as LONGBLOB instead of BLOB in the first place.

Comment: It shouldn't. A LONGBLOB uses two bytes more than a BLOB (4+L). That's pretty negligible.

Comment: Will defining LONGBLOB takes more space in DB without storing the data. Please confirm

Comment: One Byte more than BLOB, check: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, maio. Please answer my another question if possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60618804/tidy-with-itextrenderer-best-practice